# How to extract specific string part from the SQL String variable

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I have an Sql Variable which contains a string value and want to extract specific part from that string value,

```
Declare @val as nvarchar(1000),
       @outval as nvarchar(1000)

     set @val='<Message>
  <Header>
  <MessageID>000000015</MessageID>
  <MessageType>QualityData</MessageType>
   <Sender>Data</Sender>
  <Recipient>Data1</Recipient>
  <PublishedDate>2013-12-22T13:15:23</PublishedDate>
 </Header>
<Body>
 <ID>150105</ID>
 <Data>
   <Count>5</Count>
   <Brix>110</Brix>
   <CO2>110</CO2>
  </QualityData>
</Body>
</Message>'
```

Now i need to extract string from  to  using sql query. Output should be like as below.

```
      <Body>
<ID>150105</ID>
<Data>
  <Count>5</Count>
  <Brix>110</Brix>
  <CO2>110</CO2>
 </Data>
</Body>
```

any suggestion to get this format using SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Use a substring to extract the information and patindex to find the start character and length as below:

```
Select Substring(@val,PATINDEX('%<body>%', @val),PATINDEX('%</body>%', @val) - PATINDEX('%<body>%', @val) + 7)
```

Comment: Above is not returning the </body> tag as mentioned below, <Body>
<ID>150105</ID>
<Data>
  <Count>5</Count>
  <Brix>110</Brix>
  <CO2>110</CO2>
 </Data>
</Body>

Comment: @user3237193 try it now. I didn't see the </Body> part mentioned earlier

Answer (score 0):

This query may help you:

```
Declare @val as nvarchar(1000),
   @outval as nvarchar(1000),
   @start as int,
   @end as int,
   @len as int



 set @val='<Message>
  <Header>
  <MessageID>000000015</MessageID>
  <MessageType>QualityData</MessageType>
   <Sender>Data</Sender>
  <Recipient>Data1</Recipient>
  <PublishedDate>2013-12-22T13:15:23</PublishedDate>
 </Header>
<Body>
 <ID>150105</ID>
 <Data>
   <Count>5</Count>
   <Brix>110</Brix>
   <CO2>110</CO2>
  </QualityData>
</Body>
</Message>'
select @val= REPLACE(@val,'<Message>','');
select @val= REPLACE(@val,'</Message>','');
SELECT @start= CHARINDEX('<Body>', @val);
SELECT @end=CHARINDEX('</Body>', @val);
select @len= LEN (@val)
SELECT @outval= SUBSTRING ( @val ,@start ,@end- @start  )
print @outval
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your statements, I added the below line to your code. I have used the SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX in my case to solve this one, and I got exactly what you are looking for. Here is my Code: `SELECT SUBSTRING(@VAL, CHARINDEX('<Body>', @VAL), CHARINDEX('</QualityData>', @VAL) - CHARINDEX('<Body>', @VAL) + LEN('</QualityData>'))` This worked fine for me.